# Where does Allrecipes.com get its "On Sale" data?

Tags: data-request, finance, recipes

I just noticed that [Allrecipes.com](http://allrecipes.com) has a new feature that allows you to see what ingredients are on sale in local stores. Any idea where they are getting this information from?

Answer (score 6):

After taking a look at the source code of the widget on a sample recipe page (selected at random by me), it appears that they are using http://corp.groceryserver.com/ as a data provider

---

For example, the recipe at http://allrecipes.com/Recipe/Sherry-Braised-Beef-Short-Ribs/Detail.aspx makes an AJAX request to [http://allrecipes.groceryserver.com/groceryserver/service/w5fDoHvC...](http://allrecipes.groceryserver.com/groceryserver/service/w5fDoHvClcOaw4PDmSrDksKWTQpiwrFqVsKNwpbCs8OVGsKWw5YxXx8pesONb3Uwwqgzwq9VfsOaeEp7XhQ6QmZlUcKiwrhxGcOtaMOeXUx_w5PCmAnCojzCrMOkwpLCs0PCtsK4GsKQBMKvMMO8wpHDiirDiMOxbzV6w4bCpH-DrHDDhMOtwqtGwqtGwpDCmMO9w4fDkcKAFsOww6-Ci8OfwpzDn8KWbsKJwpXCtDPDqMO7wqTDrsKkHcK3e8K4wrbDhcKXNW3Dg3fDhsOXw7fDgkVLRG7DiV7CtMO9f2sfEcOsBV98JA-CrsOyNT7ChcKHYGVEw4nDuUNTwq-CvRrCvVY8wqvCuFvCqkBXw60lwpBzVcKqwoLCl8OKGh4aGcKIL0XDrFEbwobCul5SFSYzbxTDm1zCgcK6JA1CLcOmNFHDq8Kzd8Kxw4ILUMKTCcOPVMOJwoPCjcOLAnoIW8O5w48pw7QwwpzCpSAnw6kdwqHCtChGwrINw5LDlSTCtU0QGMKtPcKEwpBBVcKnw6pOw4DDvg3Dp8KIPMKXY8O7w5DDq8KPTEgWwpw9Njh8wqnClDkddsOVKD-DiMOsw4bDvsObPMKJJsOPw7-CqMKTw5zCncOdOcOMw7I7SxDDgcKvWijCghTDlATDq8OXwrMsecO9w7DDo8OQH3HCnWJnIxzCgyTCjmZdPWPCssK7QC-DvMOVJ8Oww57CqsOOw5jDg8Onw5TCrnLCuBpqfBjDgxvDsDR7wr-DliTDsMK9ZT5sw53CrsO9wrolHB4mOcOlbMOdwoTDgMOMw6geURDCsA5xw7rDkyzCosKQw4nCpcOlwrrDqsKYwprDlQ91wp1zC8K7GiA6QEjCicKfwqMxCsK8dcOGwrDDpSZVLMK9?!c!xx#) which returns JSON about the sales. Note: I tried to base64 decode that string and some variations but didn't get very far.